# Load Dojo class from string content instead of file

Tags: dojo, classloader, require

For a very special situation I want to store Dojo classes (i.e. the sources) that I load from remote in the localStorage to have access to them in offline situations (we are talking about a hybrid mobile app). I got everything running but dojo.eval won't let me create the class from a string like this

```
var data = 'define(["dojo/_base/kernel",...'; // class definition as string
dojo.eval(data);
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have your app run offline, store the resources (css, images, js) in the [app manifest](http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/manifest/). The manifest file looks like the following.

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "My elevator pitch goes here",
  "launch_path": "/",
  "icons": {
    "128": "/img/icon-128.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Your name or organization",
    "url": "http://your-homepage-here.org"
  },
  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

Your app could require hundreds of modules so for performance and manageability of the manifest, you'll want to create a [Dojo build](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/) which will reduce the number of js files to one or maybe a couple depending on how you create the build.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, standard offline handling is fine for standard situations (although I never got it to work right in hybrid apps). But I do not know the JS files in advance. During runtime I load these custom created files once based on a dynamic config file I load remotely. I want to store them to have them ready for performance reasons or for offline situations. The only missing link is the classloader define and declare that does not seem to work when run in an eval.

Comment: Just to clarify, `define()` defines modules. It does not declare Dojo classes. You need `declare()` for that. I don't understand why you need to eval the module definition. Why not just invoke `define(...)` or `require()` when you need it? What are you trying to accomplish by evaluating this string beyond just defining a module? Are you trying to gain performance by loading modules at runtime? If so, eval isn't needed. `require()` should do the trick. If you want assure that the runtime loaded modules are taken from local storage, add them to the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed what I was trying to accomplish. However, I found no way to use the localStorage and to load the classes from a string. 
The trick is to load the Dojo class source file from remote using XHR, store it using the Cordova File APIs, getting an URL to the stored file and using this URL in the require(). 
Does what I want and gives me full control over the cached files.